# Reshape + group by and rename pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, reshape

I have the following DataFrame :

```
  Police Product  PV1  PV2  PV3   PM1   PM2  PM3
0       1      AA   10    8   14   150   145  140
1       2      AB   25    4    7   700   650  620
2       3      AA   13   22    5   120    80   60
3       4      AA   12    6   12   250   170  120
4       5      AB   10   13    5   500   430  350
5       6      BC    7   21   12  1200  1000  900
```

PV1 is the item PV for year 1, PV2 for year 2, ....
I would like to combine reshaping and group by operations + some renaming stuffs to obtain the DF below :

```
  Product Item  Year1  Year2  Year3
0      AA   PV     35     36     31
1      AA   PM    520    395    320
2      AB   PV     35     17     12
3      AB   PM   1200   1080    970
4      BC   PV      7     21     12
5      BC   PM   1200   1000    900
```

It makes a group by operation on product name and reshape the DF to pass the item as a column and put the sum of each in new columns years.

I tried some tests but without success.
If you have any idea, I would be very grateful.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea is convert first columns to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then extract numeric and non numeric values to `MultiIndex` and assignback, last reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and rename columns by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Police','Product'])
L = df1.columns.str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)').T.to_numpy().tolist()

df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(L, names=['Item',None])
df1 = df1.stack(level=0).add_prefix('Year').reset_index()
print (df1)
    Police Product Item  Year1  Year2  Year3
0        1      AA   PM    150    145    140
1        1      AA   PV     10      8     14
2        2      AB   PM    700    650    620
3        2      AB   PV     25      4      7
4        3      AA   PM    120     80     60
5        3      AA   PV     13     22      5
6        4      AA   PM    250    170    120
7        4      AA   PV     12      6     12
8        5      AB   PM    500    430    350
9        5      AB   PV     10     13      5
10       6      BC   PM   1200   1000    900
11       6      BC   PV      7     21     12
```

Or use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                     i=['Police','Product'], 
                     stubnames=['PM', 'PV'], 
                     j='tmp')
       .rename_axis('Item', axis=1)
       .stack()
       .unstack(2)
       .add_prefix('year')
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       .reset_index())
print (df1)
    Police Product Item  year1  year2  year3
0        1      AA   PM    150    145    140
1        1      AA   PV     10      8     14
2        2      AB   PM    700    650    620
3        2      AB   PV     25      4      7
4        3      AA   PM    120     80     60
5        3      AA   PV     13     22      5
6        4      AA   PM    250    170    120
7        4      AA   PV     12      6     12
8        5      AB   PM    500    430    350
9        5      AB   PV     10     13      5
10       6      BC   PM   1200   1000    900
11       6      BC   PV      7     21     12
```

Comment: The first solution suits to me but I have a last issue because of the real number of years in my DF (40). The columns are in this order : year1, year11, year12,...year2,year21,....and the df.sort_index(axis=1) method doesn't seem to work. Any idea ?

Comment: I found a way to reorder the columns. Tks for your help.